What would be the best way to clean the edges of this foam spray?
This problem is in 27 basement joist bays. I started using an oscillating tool, but quickly realized I was defeating the purpose of it, as it exposed the gap behind it afterwards.
What would be the best way to clean the edges of this foam spray?
https://imgur.com/a/Ovg6Ewo

Something like a razor blade, but it looks like there was not much of a gap to begin with/not enough for the foam to go in and bite.  If the gaps are not wide, maybe clean the foam out and use caulking.

Aesthetics question removed, to keep the question on topic.

Try a sharp razor blade, knife. You'll be decreasing the insulating property though.

If there’s a gap behind, maybe you should just be pushing the bead of foam into that gap.

You might want to take a chunk outside and flame-test before you decide you want it at all.  Some if it is SCARY. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdItsso3ur0


Put the blade on the board and bend it to reach the corners. This way you will cut the foam flush.
The blade must be very sharp. Foam dulls it quickly, but a box of 100 costs about 20€. Make sure to get the absolute cheapest blades you can get: they're thinner than good quality blades, so they flex more easily, making them ideal for this.
It's also possible to resharpen it with the same tool used for kitchen knives in about 5 seconds.
It cuts much better at narrow angles, make sure to experiment and see what works best.
In the corners you'll probably need to guide the blade with your fingers. It's a good idea to wear gloves and safety glasses, in case the blade breaks.

This will work, but be careful to bend the blade as shown in the picture. Bend from the other side, and the break-off bars are more likely to break the blade and have it ping into your face.

That's true! I didn't think about it when taking the photo. It's not always possible to bend it "the right way" though. Also I'm bending it too much in the photo, to make it more obvious.

OP would have to bend it in both directions to be able to reach the corners.

An alternate idea would be an oscillating multitool with a wide blade.  It'd make short work of the foam, and is actually designed to be used at that angle.
